# simplest digital voltage selector circuit using common parts

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, voltage-regulator, multiplexer, latch

I found the following circuit for the atmel AT89LP4052 microcontroller programmer, but the bottom right section with all those transistors is an awkward way (to me) to make the input to VPP zero, 5V, or 12V. At least the chip manual dictates that one needs to apply 0, 5, and 12V on that pin at different times to make the programming successful.

This circuit came from: http://www.gms2000.de/minimikro/LP_PP_prog.htm

[image: Circuit]

So I am trying to make something simpler, so I came up with the following circuit idea:

[image: Circuit]

I will hook up the A and B lines to outputs of a latch (from a 74HC series IC) controlled by the parallel port.

I'm curious, Will my setup work successfully, or Do I need to add resistors or something between the regulator outputs and the multiplexer inputs?
I also specifically chose a cmos regulator part because I think they can work with up to 15V but the highest I would feed through because of the regulators is 12VDC.

Comment: Hi Mike, welcome to the site. Are you sure the only reason you want to use the '4051 is because it is one different from the '4052 ?

Comment: Maybe there's a chip better than what I asked for but I just want to be able to select between 0, 5, and 12VDC.

Answer (score 1):

No, your idea will not work, for two reasons, one which causes the problem of the other.

First, like most CMOS devices, it is prohibited to have any input to the 4051 chip more than a diode drop above the supply voltage.  So to use it to multiplex 12 volts, you'd have to run it on 12 volts.

Next, the threshold to reliably detect a "high" input scales with the supply voltage.   With a 10 volt supply, the you already need at least 7 volts to reliably input a logic high, and at twelve volts you will need more still.

The circuit you are objecting to is complex in the sense that it is built from discrete parts, but it is actually simpler than what is inside the IC.  More importantly, it is targeted to do what you need, *without* incurring the issues that make your idea of using a 4051 unworkable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use your idea if you replace the 4051 with a better analog multiplexer such as the [ADG1308/9](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG1308_1309.pdf) but the given circuit will be quite a bit cheaper.

The ADG1308 has inputs that are level shifted so that you can control +/-15V or 0/12V (assuming those voltage are within the supply rails, of course) with 3V or 5V logic inputs. The only 4051 contains level shifting that allows you to have a negative rail but the inputs still have to be 70% of the positive rail Vdd to be reliably switched.

Comment: hmm I don't see a DIP version of that IC that I can order at digikey or even locally. Is there another option?

Comment: Use a breakout board or look for other DIP options that have a similar function. You can do a parametric search (eg. at Digikey) and see if they might work. Eg. DG428/9

Comment: I see a CD40109 available for sale at Digikey. Could I just use that and tie the outputs together through low voltage drop diodes and then connect VDD/VCC to 5V/12V? and its inputs to 5V/0V?

Comment: I don't see how you'd use a CD40109. Output voltage is either Vdd or 0. You could use it to drive the inputs of a CD4051 (not a HC4051) powered from +12/0 -- if the on resistance of the latter is acceptable for your application.

Answer (score 1):

I see two distinct issues.

1) The generic part number "4051" is available from several different families. The CD4051 can handle a maximum voltage of (depending on manufacturer) 15 to 18 Vdc.

The 74HC4051 has, if I recall correctly, a maximum supply voltage of 11 Vdc.

2) The ON resistance of the analog switches is relatively high. This is definitely a problem when the device is required to supply significant current with minimal voltage drop.

3) The control signal voltage requirements are based on the supply voltage. You will need level translation to match the output level of the microcontroller to what the 4051 requires.

Comment: Ok so that confirms that I won't use the 74HC series of IC's. If I'm not mistaken, the VPP current requirements for microcontroller programming is small?

Answer (score 0):

I found myself an answer through LTspice experimentation. Compared to the original design, I saved some diodes. The output in this circuit is 0, 5.4V, or 12VDC. but I can change resistor values.

For inputs in this circuit, I used sinewave oscillators The first one (5Vsw) is at 1Hz and the Second one (12Vsw) is at 10Hz with a startup delay of 100mS.

[image: Circuit]